# All data is being fetched from mysql database even when not asked to in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

MySQL table- posts and i am using the following query...

```
SELECT who, votes, content, time FROM posts WHERE category = 10 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The following php code seems to work but displays all the data no matter what option is chosen...

```
<?php
            function Qfeed($cat){
                include("config.php");
                if($cat = "1"){
                    $query = "SELECT who, votes, content, time FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10";
                }elseif($cat = "2"){
                    $query = "SELECT who, votes, content, time FROM posts WHERE votes > 100 ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 10";
                }elseif($cat = "3"){
                    $query = "SELECT who, votes, content, time FROM posts WHERE DESC LIMIT 10";
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT who, votes, content, time FROM posts WHERE category = '$cat' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10";
                }
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database!');
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<article id='qpost'><section class='pvotes'><p>" .$row["votes"]. "</p></section><section class='ptitle_whoasked_time'><p class='ptitle'>" .$row["content"]. "</p><p class='pwhoasked_time'>POSTED BY " .$row["who"]. " [" .$row["time"]. "]</p></section></article>";
                    }
                }else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
                mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

            if(isset($_GET["cat"])) {
                $cat = $_GET["cat"];
                Qfeed($cat);
            }
        ?>
```

Problem: Even when I pass, say 1 through GET, i don't get the expected results.

Comment: You are assigning `=` instead of checking `===` in your `if` statements. And sql injection.

Comment: You should backtick what it's selecting as `time` is a pre set name for mysql.

Comment: @Option `time` is not a mysql reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Fred, it shows `TIME` within the reserved fields? Don't get me wrong I could be wrong here but i didn't think it mattered on the caps side for queries..?

Comment: @Option keyword and reserved are two different animals. `time` is a keyword.

Comment: Ah, my mistake :-) thanks for the heads up! I'll remember this for future reference